# Vue v-for data in component issue

Tags: vue.js, v-for

I'm trying to make as many components as my var `count_row` has via loop using v-for. But there is the issue because variable count_row = 3 in data within my component and i need to use exactly data in my template not in my Vue data. I try also use `<li v-for='i in this.count_row'>` but it doesn't work too. I googled whenever i can but i have no idea how to solve this easy problem.

```
 Vue.component('addinvexisting',{
   delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
   props:['id_inv'],
   template:`
   <div>


   <table class="table">

 <tbody>
   <tr>     
    <td><input type="text" v-model='count' name="#count" class="form- 
   control" />[[count]]</td>
    <td><textarea v-model='description' class="form-control" />[[description]]</td>
    <td><input type="text" v-model='quantity' name='quan-ty' class="form-control" />[[quantity]]</td>
    <td><input type="text" v-model='unit' class="form-control" />[[unit]]</td>
    <td><input type="text" v-model='price' name='price' class="form-control" />[[price]]</td>
    <td><input type="text" v-model='tt'  name='summTotal_w_VAT' class="form-control" />[[countSumm]]</td>
    <td>
    <select v-model='selected' class='form-control'>
        <option disabled value=''>Укажите размер НДС</option>
        <option>20</option>
        <option>0</option>
        <option>БЕЗ НДС</option>
     </select>   
        [[selected]]</td>

    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" v-model='total_t_vat'/>[[countVat]]</td>

     <td><button >Записать</button></td>


     </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>


    </div>
   `,


   data() {
      return {
         count: "",
         description: "",
         quantity: "",
         unit: "",
         amount:"",
         price: "",
         total:'',
         total_t_vat:this.countVat,
         tt:this.countSumm,
         vat: '',
         selected:'',
         count_row:3,

      }
   },



   computed:{

      countSumm(){

            this.tt = parseInt(this.price) * parseInt(this.quantity);
            this.total = this.tt
            return this.tt, this.total
      },


      countVat(){
         var c_vat =''
         if (this.price !='' & this.selected !='БЕЗ НДС'){
            c_vat = (100-parseInt(this.selected))/100
            return this.total_t_vat= parseInt(this.total)/c_vat
         }else if(this.selected =='БЕЗ НДС'){
            c_vat = parseInt(1)
            return this.total_t_vat= parseInt(this.total)/c_vat

         }
         else{
            this.price=this.price }

      },

   },
})


 const helloWorld = new Vue({
   delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
   el: '#helloVue',

   data: {

      invs:invoices,

      inv:[
         {'path': '', 'invoice_number': '11' },
         {'path': '', 'invoice_number': '12' }
      ],
      message: 'This is the message',
      name: "",

   },

   methods: {

   },


});

  <div id='helloVue'>
    <ul>
        <li v-for='i in count_row'>
                <addinvexisting></addinvexisting> 
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying "i need to use exactly data in my template not in my Vue data"?

Comment: Sorry for confusing, I mean data within my component

Comment: So inside your `addinvexisting` component you have a variable which should define how often the `<li>` should be displayed?

Comment: No, I need as many components as my variable is. If it my cont_row is 3 I need display 3 components addinvexisting, if count_row is 5 components must be 5 and so on

Comment: Dear Dan, i add all the code, could you please look at my  code and comment why it is do not working. I wondering how Vue  could understand where exactly it need to find data (data in Vue instance or Vue component). Thank you in advance

Comment: It looks like `count_row` is defined in your component, but you're trying to use it in the instance template.  Move `count_row` to the instance.

Comment: That is the goal use this.count_row  defined in component not in the instance. because each component may have different count_row. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  If there are multiple components with different `count_row`, how are you going to choose which one to use in the instance template?

Comment: the idea is use data in compoinent to pass data component  throught AJAX to the server.  Each component  must has their own data and it commited to the server via  AJAX.

Comment: It's ok for components to have their own data and communicate with the server.  But it's meaningless to say that the parent should conditionally render children based on a value that is replicated and different inside each child.  Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to do.